# how to sort data according to date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a input file in the following format:

```
457526373620277249  17644162    Sat Apr 19 14:29:22 +0000 2014  0   nc  nc  U are expressing a wish not a fact ;) @Manicdj99 @ANTIVICTORIA @Nupe117 @cspanwj
457522541926842368  402127017   Sat Apr 19 14:14:09 +0000 2014  0   nc  nc  @dfwlibrarian You're a great one to call somebody else "educationally challenged!" I'd call that a name call. #YouLose #PJNET #TCOT #TGDNGO YouLose,PJNET,TCOT,TGDNGO
457519476511350786  65713724    Sat Apr 19 14:01:58 +0000 2014  0   nc  nc  @Manicdj99 @Nupe117 @cspanwj only some RW fringies are upset- &amp; they're ALWAYS angry at something-also too fat 2 get out of lazyboys
```

I need the data to be sorted according to time. 
I am using `strptime` function but not able to sort the entire data according to time.

```
import datetime
dt=[]
for line in f:
    splits = line.split('\t')
    dt.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(splits[2], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"))
    dt.sort()
```

Comment: what you have tried so far .  ??

Comment: Can you share your attempt please?

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited the question. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to produce a list of the lines, and only then sort the whole list; you are only capturing the timestamps and are sorting that list each time you add a new timestamp, ignoring the rest of your data.

You can more easily read the data using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

rows = []
with open(yourfile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        row[2] = datetime.strptime(row[2], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
        rows.append(row)

rows.sort(key=itemgetter(2))  # sort by the datetime column
```

Comment: @Martijin Peters if I print rows, I get [].

Comment: @Saurabh: That's because I've been a numpty and forgot a line. Mea Culpa!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `data.txt` file looks like this (*I've truncated it a bit to the right*):

457526373620277249  17644162    Sat Apr 19 14:29:22 +0000 2014  0
457522541926842368  402127017   Sat Apr 19 14:14:09 +0000 2014  0
457519476511350786  65713724    Sat Apr 19 14:01:58 +0000 2014  0

I've also *assumed* it's TAB delimited here.

This will correctly parse the data, convert the dates as strings into proper [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects that can then be sorted using [`sorted(iterable, key=)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

**Example:**

```
from __future__ import print_function


from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter


def map_to_datetime(xs, index, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"):
    for x in xs:
        x[index] = datetime.strptime(x[index], format)


data = [line.split("\t") for line in map(str.strip, open("data.txt", "r"))]
map_to_datetime(data, 2)
for entry in sorted(data, key=itemgetter(2)):
    print(entry)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
['457519476511350786', '65713724', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 19, 14, 1, 58), '0']
['457522541926842368', '402127017', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 19, 14, 14, 9), '0']
['457526373620277249', '17644162', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 19, 14, 29, 22), '0']
>>>
```